# WPF begin fontsize animation of a textblock from C#

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, font-size, textblock

I would like to start a fontsize animation of a textblock from C# code. How can I do this?

I want increase/decrease fontsize during a period of 1 second.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! :) No question with all caps titles, please.

Answer (score 3):

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(20, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
MyTextBlock.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, animation);
```

Where MyTextBlock is the instance of the TextBlock you wish to animate, and 20 is the target fontsize.